# Can a matrix's column space be described with a basis that is one vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem: Construct a matrix whose column space has basis (1,1,3) and whose null space contains (1,1,-2). My question is whether a matrix can have a basis that is just one vector? As I understood it, a basis is a set of vectors.

Comment: I edited the question in response to that^

Comment: +1 for the clarification.

Comment: A basis is a set of *linearly independent* vectors.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

What about

$$A=[v\quad v\quad2v]$$

Answer (score 0):

Sets with one element are sets.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a matrix $A$ such that $A^tx=0$ with $x=(1,1,-2)$. One of $A$'s vectors is already given. So you only have to solve $\begin{pmatrix}1&1&3\\a_1&a_2&a_3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\-2\end{pmatrix}=0$. Why do I only add one row or one vector? Because the rank nullity theorem tells us that the dimension of the image plus the dimension of the kernel equals the dimension of the whole vector space, so here $2+1=3$.